# How might I divide a Google Maps display into an equal number of parts?

Tags: google-maps

I want to divide the map display area into a number of equal parts. For example: 10 parts horizontally and 15 parts vertically, resulting in 150 equal parts.

I do not know if Google Maps support such a thing...

`map.getBounds()` return the total visible area; 
so ,

```
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
alert("main: "+bounds.isEmpty());
  var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var tileWidth  = (northEast.lng() - southWest.lng()) / 10;
  var tileHeight = (northEast.lat() - southWest.lat()) / 2;

  for (var x=0; x < 10 ; x++)
{
  for (var y=0; y < 2 ; y++)
   {
    var northLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat () + (tileHeight * y);
    var westLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng () + (tileWidth * x);
    var southLat = northLat + tileHeight;
    var eastLng = westLng + tileHeight;

            var tileBounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(southLat, westLng), new GLatLng(northLat, eastLng));
    alert(tileBounds.isEmpty());

     }
 }
```

now the problem is tileBounds.isEmpty() returns TRUE !!

I cant able to find where I am missing something !!  Any Help !!

Comment: Not sure why your getBounds() call is returning an empty GLatLngBounds object.  Try a few of the other "metrics" calls on the map object (like getSize (), getCenter etc ...).  At what point are you calling this code, has the map page finished loading?  Perhaps include a link to your example?

Comment: The problem is solved, I was doing wrong with x1,y1 and x2,y2 co-ordinates for GLatLngBounds contractor.    Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi you might want to look into my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221730/divide-a-path-into-equal-parts-in-google-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are after the region coordinates for the 150 smaller tiles?

map.getBounds () returns a GLatLngBounds object.  This includes getSouthWest () and getNorthEast () methods.  So from the latitude/longitude values for the bottom left and top right hand corners of the visible map you could derive the coordinates of the set of 150 smaller regions:

- Divide the width (longitude of getNorthEast () - longitude of getSouthWest ()) by 15, to determine tile width.
- Divide the height (latitude of getNorthEast () - latitude of getSouthWest ()) by 10, to determine tile height.
- calculate the coordinates for a particular cell based on it's offset in x and y multiplied by the width and height.

So to instantiate a GLatLngBounds(sw?:GLatLng, ne?:GLatLng) for a particular cell index (x, y):

```
// bounds is the map.getBounds () result
northLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat () + (tileHeight * y);
westLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng () + (tileWidth * x);
southLat = northLat + tileHeight;
eastLng = westLng + tileHeight;

tileBounds = new GLatLngBounds (new GLatLng (southLat, westLng), new GLatLng (northLat, eastLng));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am almost there.
But confuse on How to get the coordinates for a particular cell and how to get it's offset in x and y ?

Comment: just a minute thing ,

tileHeight  and tileWidth  I will get bye,
tileWidth  = (bounds.getNorthEast.lng() - bounds.getSouthWest.lng()) / 10;
tileHeight = (bounds.getNorthEast.lat() - bounds.getSouthWest.lat()) / 15;

but how to retrieve x and y to get northLat or westLng  value ?

Comment: i.e. how  to get particular cells x, y point ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: I am using x and y just a logical index into the array of cells, so the top left cell is x=0,y0,  bottom right cell is x=9, y=14, etc ... so you could build a nested for loop to generate the region for each tile.

Comment: I cannot able to use the 'tileBounds' which I am getting,

tileBounds.isEmpty() returns TURE , I am accepting a FALSE value for  tileBounds.isEmpty() call. any idea.

Comment: any Help on this , actually what want wrong in implementation.

Comment: @Sujoy Can you give the complete code which is useful

Comment: @RedBlueThing Can you provide the complete code for dividing google map into equal parts, which is helpful to my project