# Android Google Maps - How to divide Google Maps route in equal segments?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my custom Google Maps, I draw a route between two locations (say Pune to Mumbai) using this URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Pune&destination=Mumbai&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=false
```

[image]

Parsing this response I get number of points between source and destination and store it in `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<LocationModel> listAllPoints = getPoints();
```

This `ArrayList` contains around 2600 points.

My question is, how can I divide this route in 10 equal segments, i.e. total 11 points including source and destination. Like this

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |

Where | = each point, Character = segment

Distance between A and B, B and C, C and D should be equal.

I should be able to do this by dividing `listAllPoints` in 11 Parts, but problem is that, points inside `listAllPoints` are not scattered uniformly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to add multiple waypoints on map with create path?

Comment: check this may be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919243/how-might-i-divide-a-google-maps-display-into-an-equal-number-of-parts

Answer (score 0):

Refer this simple code.

1. Get Document

   ```
               String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
           + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
           + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
           + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";


       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
       InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
       DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       Document    document = builder.parse(in);
   ```
2. Draw line:

   ```
              ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = v2GetRouteDirection
                       .getDirection(document);
               PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10)
                       .color(Color.RED);

               for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                   rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
               }
               // Adding route on the map
               mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
   ```
3. Add Point

   ```
              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
              Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                       EMaps2.this.getResources(), R.drawable.pointa);
                   markerOptions
                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
               markerOptions.position(fromPosition);
               markerOptions.title("Point A");
               mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
   ```

Comment: This code simply draws a line on Map. I have already done it. How can I split that route in equal segments?